# Testing React-Bootstrap components with Mocha

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, webpack, react-bootstrap

How can I test React-Bootstrap components with node.js outside the browser? I am using Webpack. Since I'm running headless, I specify the `null-loader` for styles in my webpack config:

```
{test: /(\.css|\.less)$/, loader: 'null-loader'}
```

Nevertheless, I get an error when I run `mocha` that shows that the `style-loader` is being used:

```
webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:14
        return /msie [6-9]\b/.test(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
                                   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at eval (webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:14:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:9:47)
    at module.exports (webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:31:68)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/bootstrap-webpack/bootstrap.config.js?./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./~/bootstrap-webpack/bootstrap-styles.loader.js:7:38)
[...]
```

It looks like this is because `bootstrap-webpack` is using the style loader even though my code isn't.

I've uploaded a full but minimal project to GitHub so you can [take a look](https://github.com/DanLipsitt/webpack-bootstrap-mocha-example).

Answer (score 0):

*bootstrap-webpack* allows you to override its config. Just create file *bootstrap.config.js* and specify it in the import:

*bootstrap.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  styleLoader: 'null-loader',
  scripts: {
    // add every bootstrap script you need
    'transition': false
  },
  styles: {
    // add every bootstrap style you need
    "mixins": true,

    "normalize": true,
    "print": true,

    "scaffolding": true,
    "type": true,
  }
};
```

*App.jsx*

```
import 'bootstrap-webpack!../../bootstrap.config.js';
```